# InvalidCacheBackendError at /

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I am trying to install python environment for Ubuntu for already existing project.

1. I installed all the requirements listed using pip install requirements.txt.
2. Created a virtual environment using "mkvirtualenv".
3. Run the server using manage.py.

I have Django version 1.6.1 And it hits an error:

> **InvalidCacheBackendError at /**
>
> Could not find backend 'session': Could not find backend 'session':
>   session doesn't look like a module path

I have never done python development, I am working on the front-end of the project. Please help.

Here is traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:9000/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'yellow_web',
 'django_extensions',
 'django_nose',
 'compressor',
 'tracking',
 'users',
 'review',
 'api',
 'yellowdesigns',
 'analytics',
 'ctn',
 'sitemaps',
 'seo',
 'selfservice',
 'contact_forms')
Installed Middleware:
('yellow_web.lib.middlewares.SubdomainMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'yellow_web.lib.middlewares.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
 'yellow_web.lib.middlewares.SearchUUIDMiddleware',
 'yellow_web.lib.middlewares.UpstreamServerErrorTrapMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/said/virtualenvs/berillium/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  90.                 response = middleware_method(request)
File "/home/said/virtualenvs/berillium/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py" in process_request
  12.         request.session = engine.SessionStore(session_key)
File "/home/said/virtualenvs/berillium/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/cache.py" in __init__
  14.         self._cache = get_cache(settings.SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS)
File "/home/said/virtualenvs/berillium/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py" in get_cache
  130.             "Could not find backend '%s': %s" % (backend, e))

Exception Type: InvalidCacheBackendError at /
Exception Value: Could not find backend 'session': Could not find backend 'session': session doesn't look like a module path
```

Comment: Can you provide the trace back to your error or a screen shot of your terminal when the error occurs?

Comment: Also can you provide your settings, or more specifically your `CACHES` settings.

Comment: CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}} @vishen